# How did adding new pages to a US passport use to work?

Tags: usa, passports, us-citizens, history

[Until 2016](https://2009-2017.state.gov/r/pa/prs/ps/2015/11/249675.htm), it was possible to add 24 new pages to a US passport:

> The U.S. Department of State will no longer add visa pages into U.S. passports beginning January 1, 2016. Previously, U.S. passport holders had the option to pay for the insertion of additional 24-page visa inserts when valid passports lacked adequate space for entry or exit visa stamps.

How were the pages added to the passport? Were they physically sewn to the existing passport in the middle or attached at the end? Or was it done in some other way?

Comment: Related: https://www.passport-collector.com/world-record-the-fattest-passport/

Comment: Granted, the guy had free airfare, but how in the world did he travel enough during the validity of a single passport to need to add that many pages??

Comment: Follow-up: [Which regulation stipulated that the maximum number of pages allowed in a US passport was 100?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178854/1810)

Comment: Another follow-up: [Does any country still offer their citizens the option to add new pages on their passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178864/1810)

Comment: @JonathanReez I found almost the same article but with clearer writing: https://www.smithsonianmag.com/travel/meet-man-largest-us-passport-180958024/

Comment: @FreeMan in the article(s) stannius/JonathanReez link, he says "I would fly to Tokyo, have dinner and come back". I can see how that would add up.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Around 20 years ago they were taped in with a
wide  strip of fairly thick transparent plastic adhesive tape.  The page linked in the other answer misinterprets this slightly.  The additional pages are a sewn booklet.  They are not "sewn into the passport."  I believe the sewn booklet includes the adhesive plastic strip, but that is obviously stuck into the passport, not sewn.  I'll try to remember to check my old passport tomorrow to confirm.

Comment: Thanks, did you get a chance to check my old passport tomorrow to confirm?

Answer (score 13):

This [site](https://www.notcot.com/archives/2011/03/adding-passport-pages.php) ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20200710022906/https://www.notcot.com/archives/2011/03/adding-passport-pages.php)) (not mine) has pictures of the page addition

[image]
[image]

More photos in the website

Comment: Kudos for including the Internet Archive address! I spend so much time hunting those down to fix link rot :)

Answer (score 7):

For a Type VIII (1961-01-01 / 1975-12-01) Passport, where the pages were numbered up to 19, the extension (called **additional sheet**) was glued on to a page near the end (here page 16) and affixed with 2 seals (top and bottom).

The *additional sheet* contained six, double sided, pages and were not numbered. This sheet was added in the spring of 1972.

[image]
[image]