# Which regulation stipulated that the maximum number of pages allowed in a US passport was 100?

Tags: usa, passports

I read on https://www.smithsonianmag.com/travel/meet-man-largest-us-passport-180958024/:

> The maximum number [of pages] allowed [in a US passport] used to be capped at 100?

Which regulation stipulated that the maximum number of pages allowed in a US passport was 100?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a legal question and should be migrated to law@SE

Answer (score 2):

It was (indirectly) stipulated in [7 FAM 1300 Appendix V, Supplemental Visa Page Inserts](https://archive.org/details/nsia-7FAM1300AppendixVSupplementalVisaPageInsertsbyU.S.DepartmentofState5p1.5vtr):

> a. Each set of supplemental visa page inserts (also known as "visa
> page inserts") adds an additional 24 pages to a passport. They extend
> the useful life of a passport as an accommodation to individuals who
> travel frequently to countries requiring visas.
>
> ...
>
> c. The Bureau of Consular Affairs (CA) recommends adding no more than
> two sets of visa page inserts to a passport for the reason that the
> added thickness may result in damage to the binding of the book during
> its validity.

Since US passports can have at most 52 pages without extensions and you can get at most two 24-page "visa page inserts", the total maximum number of pages should be 52+24*2 = 100.

Comment: Nice find! "may result in damage to the binding of the book during its validity." -> My main surprise with the 331-page passport guy was that he managed to add all these pages indeed. Reminds me of the bypass burgers from the Heart Attack Grill.