# Does any country still offer their citizens the option to add new pages on their passport?

Tags: passports

[Until 2016](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/178825/1810), it was possible to add new pages to a US passport. Does any country still offer their citizens the option to add new pages on their passport?

Comment: I suspect that international passport standards prohibit this. Countries typically offer the option of requesting a passport with extra pages, or even an additional passport eg https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/additional-passports/additional-passports-accessible

Comment: At the time of applying you can ask for a UK passport with more pages (I know that is not strictly what you want).

Answer (score 2):

> Does any country still offer their citizens the option to add new pages on their passport?

I have never seen, nor heard of, any other country than the US that added new pages to their passports when they were full.

The more interesting question would be, other than the US, which countries offered to add new pages to their passport?

The original **League of Nations Passport Conferences** of the 1920's, where the first norms (as a recommendation) were developed, did not forsee adding pages to a passport, but replacing a fill passport with a fresh passport.

> Annex I
> Type of "International” Passport.
> The passport is to contain 32 pages. The first four pages only are reproduced herewith.
> The other 28 pages should all be numbered and should contain the visas of the countries for which the passport is valid.
> The passport should be drawn up in at least two languages, i.e., in the national language and in French.
> The passport must be bound in cardboard, bearing on the top the name and in the centre the coat of arms of the country and at the bottom the word "Passport”, with the addition, according to the desire of the various Governments, of any practical information concerning the regime of passports.
> *Any passport of which the pages are entirely filled **must** be replaced by a fresh passport*.

The recommendations were, however, not always followed:

[image]

---

The ICAO recommendations advices against additional visa pages, since it can interfere with the machine authentication.

> Doc 9303, Machine Readable Travel Documents
> Part 2 — Specifications for the Security of the Design, Manufacture and Issuance of MRTDs
>
> C.4.1.2 Potentially interfering features for machine authentication
> ...
> **Additional visa pages**: Passports that can be amended with additional visa page inserts can become too massive for ordinary full page reader geometries.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Can you please edit the answer in?

Comment: @Willeke How do you prove a negative? I have cited both of the pre-war and todays recommendations and have shown an early sample from the only known country that did not follow the original recommendation in this regard.

Comment: Maybe by stating, early in the answer you do not know countries that still do, followed by the reasons (is the current answer.)

Comment: @Willeke Making a statement of fact, without knowing is not something that is done in history or law. Laying out what is known (and for conventions countries could always option out on individual points that are agreed to) and then letting other come to their own conclusions is how such matters should be delt with. The original first line suggested what the question should be and the rest the reasons why.

Comment: I have a vague memory of France allowing it a long time ago (but the practice has been discontinued for at least a decade, possibly a lot more).

Comment: @Willke And yet on Travel many question are about law nevertheless. In the end, it the author that decides how their answer is to be written.

Comment: @jcaron in the 1980's a french friend of mine recieved a new passport after his was filled with polish visas. The new passport contained more pages than the standard one if I remember correctly.

Comment: The UK offered, and maybe still does, extra large passports if you anticipated the problem.  Even the standard old British blue hard cover passports were large; the extended ones rivalled War And Peace.